# Script when opening in the mobile version of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile

It is necessary that, in the mobile version of the Google spreadsheet (on a mobile phone), the script scrolls / activates the bottom cell of the table.

In the desktop version of Google Spreadsheets It works!! :

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSelection('A'+ss.getLastRow());
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

But this script does not work in a mobile phone (maybe due to the reduced capabilities of the mobile version of the table).

But still I hope - Connoisseurs will prompt me something!

Comment: Rearrange you're data, such that latest data are always at the top

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, onOpen() triggers do not work on mobile (as stated by Ryan), nor is there an AppScript or Macro menu. One thing that does work, though, is onEdit() triggers.

From my experience, the only way to accomplish something like this would be to implement an `onEdit()` function with a checkbox. This method would not be automatic when opening the sheet, but upon opening the sheet on mobile, the user could then check off that box, and the script would run. Let me know if this is a method you would be interested in trying out, and I can edit this post to provide you with some code (I am not providing it initially since it doesn't really answer your question or truly solve your issue).

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question.
But the most important thing for me was - is it possible to make the script scroll / activate the bottom cell of the Google spreadsheet in the mobile version?

Comment: I have just tested it and it seems that, while the script will run on mobile, it doesn't properly activate the bottom cell. I am not sure if there are ways to make it work, though I will look into it and let you know

Comment: @alexche see this thread for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47205197/google-script-on-android-to-activate-select-a-cell

Comment: kaitlynmm569 !
 
Thanks again for trying to help me!
It looks like at the current time my task cannot be implemented in the mobile version of Google Sheets.

Answer (score -1):

This probably isn't an issue with your code but the fact that googles mobile apps don't support Google Script or their triggers, Try using the mobile browser view of google sheets that might work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).